# How can I get a reference to the instance from a bound method?

Tags: python, methods

Is it possible to access the object to which a bound method is bound?

```
class NorwegianBlue(object):

    def hello(self):
        print "Well, he's...he's, ah...probably pining for the fjords"

    def some_method(self):
        pass

thing = NorwegianBlue().some_method
the_instance = ???
thing.im_class.hello(the_instance)
```

Comment: for future readers: use `im_self` in python < 2.6, `__self__` otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bound methods have a `__self__` and `im_self` attribute:

```
>>> thing = NorwegianBlue().some_method
>>> thing.__self__
<__main__.NorwegianBlue object at 0x100294c50>
>>> thing.im_self
<__main__.NorwegianBlue object at 0x100294c50>
```

`im_self` is the old name; `__self__` is the Python 3 name.

You may find the [`inspect` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) helpful; it contains a table of attributes per object type.

The attributes are described in more detail in the [reference *Data Model* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).